# Performing calculations writing answers in standard form

Tags: notation, real-numbers

I have the question "Perform the following calculation writing your answer in standard form:

$$\frac {1.94925 \times 10^8}   {3.45 \times 10^3}\tag{1}$$

I'm not sure whether the answer is $\frac{19492500}{3450} = 56500$. And then in standard form this should be $5.65 \times 10^4$

***OR***

Whether the answer should be $\frac {1.94925}{3.45} = 0.565$ and then using the rules of powers do $\frac {10^8}{10 ^3} = 10 ^5$

Therefore giving the answer as $0.565 \times 10^5$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplied number in scientific notation has to be larger than $0$, but less than $1$. $$1\leq a\leq 10$$

In the form $a\times 10^b$. So $5.65\times 10^4 $ is correct.

Comment: You said "The multiplied number in scientific notation has to be larger than 0, but less than 1" but your example has it between 1 and 10!  I believe what is called "**engineering notation**" has a between 0 and 1.
.

Comment: @user247327 Yes, I have changed that after I realized that. Sorry! :(